# Can I use Azure AD Connect to connect an Azure AD and a local AD with the same domain name?

Tags: azure-active-directory

As the title says,

Can I use Azure AD Connect to connect an Azure AD and a local AD with the same domain name?

**Azure AD domain:** example.com
**Local AD domain:** example.com

Will it allow me to do it or will it end up in an error?
Or maybe it will only allow me to do specific setups? ie: Can do Password sync but not federate it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use Azure AD Connect to connect an Azure AD and a local AD with the same domain name?

Yes, that's how Azure AD works. And to ensure Azure AD connect to work successfully, we need to verify the domain for Azure AD first. More detail about this topic you can refer the links below:

[Getting started with Azure AD Connect using express settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-express)

[Add a custom domain name to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain)